# karma can I mock service but not include it

Tags: angularjs, testing, karma-jasmine

My test is running into an error saying the following from and angular site

> Unknown provider: UserServiceProvider <- UserService <- ResourceService <- taOptions
>
> Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.10/$injector/unpr?p0=UserServiceProvider%20%3C-%20User
>   Service%20%3C-%20ResourceService%20%3C-%20taOptions

When I include the service on karma.conf it tells me there are errors on the service.js and is trying to test it. Is there a way for me to mock the service without including it?

I tried it like this but it isn't working:

```
inject(function(_$injector_) {
  var $controller;
  this.httpBackend = _$injector_.get('$httpBackend');
  this.rootScope = _$injector_.get('$rootScope');
  $controller = _$injector_.get('$controller');
  this.scope = this.rootScope.$new();
  $q = $injector.get('$q');

  this.UserService = {

  };
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the $provide component to return back a mock object for you service.

```
beforeEach(module(function($provide) {
    $provide.service('yourServiceName', function() {});
}));
```

Docs for $provide - https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$provide